# Error in step(Fitallreport) : number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to use a backward step regression on my data set to see which variables have the most impact one of my others. I have searched my data and there is no empty cells or NAs that I can find. I am still a rookie level when it comes to R so please treat me if I am dumb when it comes to this.

```
studentreport<-read.csv(mydata.csv,header=T,sep=",")
```

studentreport<-data.frame(studentreport)
Fitallreport<-glm(Enrolling~.,data=studentreport,family=binomial)
step(Fitallreport)

When I run it goes like this

```
studentreport<-read.csv(mydata.csv,header=T,sep=",")
```

> studentreport<-data.frame(studentreport)
>   Fitallreport<-glm(Enrolling~.,data=studentreport,family=binomial)
>   Warning message:
>   glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
>   step(Fitallreport)
>   Start:  AIC=394
>       Enrolling ~ School + City + State + Birthdate + Gender + Race + 
>       TShirt + Major + ACT + SAT + Rank + CSize + GPA + GPAType

```
Step:  AIC=394
Enrolling ~ School + City + State + Birthdate + Gender + Race + 
TShirt + Major + ACT + SAT + Rank + CSize + GPA


Step:  AIC=394
Enrolling ~ School + City + State + Birthdate + Gender + Race + 
TShirt + Major + ACT + SAT + Rank + CSize


Step:  AIC=394
Enrolling ~ School + City + State + Birthdate + Gender + Race + 
TShirt + Major + ACT + SAT + Rank


Step:  AIC=394
Enrolling ~ School + City + State + Birthdate + Gender + Race + 
TShirt + Major + ACT + SAT


Step:  AIC=394
Enrolling ~ School + City + State + Birthdate + Gender + Race + 
TShirt + Major + ACT


Step:  AIC=394
Enrolling ~ School + City + State + Birthdate + Gender + Race + 
TShirt + Major


Step:  AIC=394
Enrolling ~ School + City + State + Birthdate + Gender + Race + 
TShirt


Step:  AIC=394
Enrolling ~ School + City + State + Birthdate + Gender + Race

Error in step(Fitallreport) : 
  number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 
50)
>
```

When I try to bring up the warnings it comes up blank. Also, if I wanted to respond to this question it poses how do I do this? I was going to use lm over glm but enrollment is just true and false so I figured glm is better, was that a bad assumption?

I hope I gave enough information.

```
> str(studentreport)
'data.frame':   200 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Enrolling: logi  FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ School   : Factor w/ 176 levels "Academy for the Arts, Science and Technology",..: 155 25 110 141 79 46 89 19 83 83 ...
 $ City     : Factor w/ 154 levels "Albany","Ames",..: 64 82 56 132 135 81 122 2 77 77 ...
 $ State    : Factor w/ 27 levels "AL","CA","CT",..: 6 25 25 18 3 3 2 8 18 18 ...
 $ Birthdate: Factor w/ 157 levels "1/11/00","1/12/00",..: 145 107 71 153 133 85 144 127 104 104 ...
 $ Gender   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Female","Male",..: 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Race     : Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","D","E",..: 6 6 6 1 1 3 6 6 1 6 ...
 $ TShirt   : Factor w/ 5 levels "2X","L","M","S",..: 2 4 4 2 3 1 2 3 4 4 ...
 $ Major    : Factor w/ 35 levels "Accounting","Art History",..: 19 16 7 6 23 28 23 7 34 34 ...
 $ ACT      : int  28 22 25 25 31 24 29 25 24 24 ...
 $ SAT      : num  1950 1390 1625 1540 1625 ...
 $ Rank     : int  60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 ...
 $ CSize    : int  337 337 337 337 337 337 337 337 337 337 ...
 $ GPA      : num  4.46 3.8 4.17 3.22 3.8 ...
 $ GPAType  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Unweighted","Weighted": 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 
...
```

> 

```
> summary(studentreport)
 Enrolling                                  School              City    
 Mode :logical   Lexington High School         :  4   Columbia    :  6  
 FALSE:160       Socastee High School          :  3   Lexington   :  6  
 TRUE :40        Beaufort High School          :  2   Myrtle Beach:  5  
                 Clover High School            :  2   Charleston  :  4  
                 Greenwood High School         :  2   Rock Hill   :  4  
                 Hilton Head Island High School:  2   Conway      :  3  
                 (Other)                       :185   (Other)     :172  
     State      Birthdate      Gender    Race   TShirt 
  SC     :78   2/25/00:  4   Female:135   A:60   2X:29  
  MD     :15   1/17/00:  3   Male  : 60   B: 2   L :38  
  NJ     :13   3/30/00:  3   Other :  2   D:25   M :66  
  NY     :13   4/13/00:  3   NA's  :  3   E: 3   S :61  
  MA     :11   5/19/00:  3                F:18   XL: 6  
  FL     : 7   6/1/00 :  3                G:92          
 (Other):63   (Other):181                              
                     Major         ACT             SAT            Rank      
 Business Administration:28   Min.   :17.00   Min.   : 910   Min.   :  2.0  
 Biology                :27   1st Qu.:24.00   1st Qu.:1540   1st Qu.: 60.0  
 Undecided              :25   Median :25.00   Median :1625   Median : 60.0  
 Communication          :15   Mean   :25.02   Mean   :1619   Mean   : 73.8  
 Psychology             :11   3rd Qu.:25.00   3rd Qu.:1655   3rd Qu.: 62.0  
 Marketing              : 9   Max.   :35.00   Max.   :2090   Max.   :426.0  
 (Other)                :85                                                 
     CSize            GPA              GPAType   
 Min.   : 22.0   Min.   :2.703   Unweighted: 13  
 1st Qu.:331.5   1st Qu.:3.428   Weighted  :187  
 Median :337.0   Median :3.822                   
 Mean   :337.8   Mean   :3.864                   
 3rd Qu.:337.0   3rd Qu.:4.281                   
 Max.   :990.0   Max.   :5.590
```